# Is there a specific term for when an artist covers a song in a different musical style?

Tags: identify-this-genre, terminology

Lately I've had a lot of fun listening to instrumental covers of modern songs created with medieval music instruments (example:

). This also lead me down the rabbit hole of artists who do the same but with a variety of musical styles and national styles (example: VinHeteiro, like

).

My question is: is there a specific term for such a composition? I feel like cover is too generic, and I always interpreted "medley" as being about multiple songs from the same artist or in the same style.

Comment: "Medley" is just the term for several different pieces combined into one. Often there's a theme e.g. a particular artist or a particular style, but often not. One piece in different styles wouldn't normally be called a medley.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would "reinterpretation" be the word you're looking for?

["Weird Al" Yankovic - My Bologna (Audio) - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1hxLaFJf9Jk) is a parody, not a real cover, but he's used the accordion to play many other songs that were never intended for such an instrument.

Or [Johnny Cash - Hurt (Official Music Video) - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8AHCfZTRGiI), which *is* a cover, of the Nine Inch Nails piece, in a completely different style.